# Can 3rd party apps access app specific external storage?

Tags: android, android-storage

I read documentation about app specific storage in Android: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

In the first row of the table it's said that other apps can't access app specific files. Am I right that it's a mistake in the documentation?

I think so, since in the next [article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific#external), it's said that

> On devices that run Android 9 (API level 28) or lower, your app can
> access the app-specific files that belong to other apps, provided that
> your app has the appropriate storage permissions.

Also, I tested it in practice. I saved a pdf file under `File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "book.pdf")`, and found this book in file explorer under `Android/data/<my app>/files/book.pdf`. I use Redmi Note 5 Pro, Android 9, not rooted. File explorer is not build in, but downloaded from Google Play, so couldn't have higher permissions from the producer.

Comment: You may want to read Commonsware's blog posts to get a history of [internal](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), [external](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/11/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Android provide following locations to store data

Internal storage directories: These directories include both a dedicated location for storing persistent files, and another location for storing cache data. The system prevents other apps from accessing these locations, and on Android 10 (API level 29) and higher, these locations are encrypted. These characteristics make these locations a good place to store sensitive data that only your app itself can access.

External storage directories: These directories include both a dedicated location for storing persistent files, and another location for storing cache data. Although it's possible for another app to access these directories if that app has the proper permissions, the files stored in these directories are meant for use only by your app